# How to know what is the weight of a web request in Javascript only?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, http-headers, google-tag-manager, web-performance

As a Web Analyst, I am trying to know what the actual difference is between **Client side data collection** vs **Server Side data collection** for the web performance.

For my website, I injected 2 Google Tag Manager (GTM) containers on the client side :

**Client container 1** : Used for Server side tracking only :

- 1 big data flow is sent to my server side GTM container.

**Client container 2** : Used for Client side tracking only :

- Multiple data flows are defined and sent to the chosen third party tools.

At this point, I know that my first container used for server side tracking is lighter than the 2nd one. The thing is that I would like to track what the actual difference is in terms of weight, for a page.

In the end, my objective is to show that, for a single page, 30kb is nothing, but when you analyse the difference between both implementation methods for a big platform that does 300.000.000 sessions a year, the difference is counted into Terabytes for this slight implementation method difference.

I know that some similar questions were posted here, but I can not figure out how to make the "solutions" work.

[As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Ugj.png), I would like to try and get the following information for each request in Javascript :

- Size
- Time spent
- URL
- Type (Javascript, image, ...)
- Distinct if a request is in cache or not

In the end, I would agregate the result of this thing inside an array before sending the data to my analytics tools.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'customEvent',
    'event_type': 'global_performance',
    
    'request_list': [{
        'request_shortened_url': "GTM-XXXXXXXX", // str - Simplified request URL (or full URL if too complex for some cases)
        'request_size': 10, // short - size of the request, in bytes
        'request_time': 54, // short - time taken by the request, in ms
        'request_type': "javascript", // str - request type (is it either a javascript code, an image, or else...)
        'request_cached': true, // bool - True if the request is in cache, false otherwise
    },{
        /* And so on for the other requests */
    }]
});
```

I definitely know that third party tools like Google Analytics, Matomo, Piwik Pro, Adobe Analytics, Piano (etc...) are not designed to workaround this kind of issues natively, but I would love to give it a try.

I already spent hours trying to make this kind of thing work, without any success.

Thank you in advance for your answers. Do not hesitate asking questions if I am unclear.

Comment: Not sure this number needs to be in the GA4 or similar analytic platform. Maybe we don't need 100% user's data. I guess a crawler which can detect the gtm container's request and get the size and loading time would be enough. Recently I used Puppeteer in NodeJS to check the tracking request. It might be a way.

Comment: I have to agree that this type of data does not need to be brought to GA4 in the long term.

I want to see whether a particular tag must be triggered on Pageview, DOM Ready, or full page loaded. Plus a dimension on how does server side tracking affects everything.

I read some articles saying that it is better to go for tag triggering on full page load since most important content passes at the beginning of the pageview, which seems obvious.

The issue is that the process to achieve those results is unclear to me.

This way, I would be able to make the quantity serve the quality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but when you analyse the difference between both implementation methods for a big platform that does 300.000.000 sessions a year, the difference is counted into Terabytes for this slight implementation method difference.

You correctly compare the 30kb difference to the size of the page, but then you fail to do the comparison right after it. If you want to look at abstract absolute numbers, you should compare it to other abstract absolute numbers. In this case, an adequate comparison would be to the total Internet traffic in a year. In short, the terabytes of difference is nothing.

Another issue is your DL usage. You don't need DL for this unless you want to offload this work to the front-end. You generally just want to contain this logic in a CJS variable in GTM.

Finally, yes, you can get your hands on that information. Through the [performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance)

Here, take a look:

[image]
[image]

That should be ample for this kind of tracking.

That said, I wouldn't be wasting a dimension on this. Maybe I would want to track time to interactive, but tracking every library load times is an overkill in vast majority of cases, including large enterprise sites. There's absolutely no business case to build with just large absolute numbers not being properly cross-referenced and compared to proper industry standards.

Comment: First thanks for the link to the performance API ! It helps a lot. I am not worried about the dimension factor since this type of work would be done in GA4, which allows 50 event based custom dimensions. Also, this test would be done internally, on a limited user number. A projection would then be done depending on user's network's quality for example. My comparisons would be done on the right scopes in the end. I simply went too fast with the 30kb for 1 page that brings to N Terabytes in a year. Since my clients are non technical, they often want to see big numbers to caricature the thing...

Comment: You generally just want to contain this logic in a CJS variable in GTM.
-> Yes, that's the goal ! The DataLayer example was just given to summarize how my structure would be. Sorry for the unclear explanation ! :)

Comment: Yeah, then it makes sense. Good luck with your proof of concept. Keep in mind that 50 is the limit for CDs. 25 is the limit for ep/event.

Answer (score 1):

here are some updates on my workaround with the Performance API.

```
    function() {
    // Get all performance entries
    var perf = performance.getEntries();
    // Create an empty object to store resource information
    var resources = {};

    // Iterate through each performance entry
    perf.forEach(function(entry) {
        // Get the initiator type or entry type as the resource type (unit: string)
        var type = entry.initiatorType || entry.entryType;

        // If the resource type is not in the resources object, initialize it with default values
        if (!resources[type]) {
            resources[type] = {
                count: 0, // Unit: count of resources (integer)
                encodedBodySize: {},
                decodedBodySize: {},
                duration: {},
                names: [] // Unit: array of resource names (strings)
            };
        }

        // Reference the resource object for the current resource type
        var resource = resources[type];
        // Increment the resource count
        resource.count++;

        // Add the resource name to the names array
        resource.names.push(entry.name);

        // Iterate through each required metric (encodedBodySize, decodedBodySize, duration)
        ['encodedBodySize', 'decodedBodySize', 'duration'].forEach(function(metric) {
            // Get the value for the current metric
            // encodedBodySize and decodedBodySize units: bytes (integer)
            // duration unit: milliseconds (float)
            var value = entry[metric];

            // Initialize the total object for the current metric if it doesn't exist
            if (!resource[metric].total) {
                resource[metric].total = { value: 0, count: 0 };
            }
            // Increment the total value and count for the current metric
            resource[metric].total.value += value;
            resource[metric].total.count++;

            // Iterate through each required statistic (minimum, minimum_excluding_0, maximum, average)
            ['minimum', 'minimum_excluding_0', 'maximum', 'average'].forEach(function(stat) {
                // Initialize the stat object for the current metric if it doesn't exist
                if (!resource[metric][stat]) {
                    resource[metric][stat] = { value: 0, count: 0, names: [] };
                }
            });

            // If the value is 0, update the minimum statistic for the current metric
            if (value === 0) {
                resource[metric].minimum.value = 0;
                resource[metric].minimum.count++;
                resource[metric].minimum.names.push(entry.name);
            } else if (value > 0) { // If the value is greater than 0, update other statistics for the current metric
                // Update the minimum_excluding_0 statistic if it's the first occurrence or the value is lower than the current minimum
                if (resource[metric].minimum_excluding_0.value === 0 || value < resource[metric].minimum_excluding_0.value) {
                    resource[metric].minimum_excluding_0.value = value;
                    resource[metric].minimum_excluding_0.count = 1;
                    resource[metric].minimum_excluding_0.names = [entry.name];
                } else if (value === resource[metric].minimum_excluding_0.value) { // If the value is equal to the current minimum, increment the count and add the name to the list
                    resource[metric].minimum_excluding_0.count++;
                    resource[metric].minimum_excluding_0.names.push(entry.name);
                }

                // Update the maximum statistic if it's the first occurrence or the value is higher than the current maximum
                if (value > resource[metric].maximum.value) {
                    resource[metric].maximum.value = value;
                    resource[metric].maximum.count = 1;
                    resource[metric].maximum.names = [entry.name];
                } else if (value === resource[metric].maximum.value) { // If the value is equal to the current maximum, increment the count and add the name to the list
                    resource[metric].maximum.count++;
                    resource[metric].maximum.names.push(entry.name);
                }
            }

            // Calculate the average value for the current metric
            resource[metric].average.value = resource[metric].total.value / resource[metric].total.count;
            resource[metric].average.count = resource[metric].total.count;
            resource[metric].average.names = resource.names;
        });
    });

    return resources;
}
```

This code goes through the performance entries and returns an object that does the following things :

- Sort each request by type ("beacon", "css", "iframe", "img", "link", "script", "xmlhttprequest", etc...).

[Illustration example for the request types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM18R.png)

For each type, the following information is stored :

- total number of requests (counter)
- decodedBodySize (bytes)
- duration (milliseconds)
- encodedBodySize (bytes)
- resource name (array of strings)

[Illustration example for the information listed above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/085Ee.png)

And for each variable (decodedBodySize, encodedBodySize, duration), there is one last sub object that gives the following information :

- average (decodedBodySize, encoded, duration)
- maximum (same logic as above)
- minimum
- minimum_excluding_0 (some resources count as having a 0 bytes bodySize, either if it is encoded or decoded. I did not figure out how to measure the page weight of those resources for the moment excluding the resource duration).

[Illustration example for the information listed above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZORK.png)

### Next steps

- There are still some mistakes to correct. For example, the "average" sub object returns the total number of resource names...
- Figure out how to rewrite the resource names properly to gain space for data collection, since custom dimensions in GA4 can not contain more than 255 characters.
- Figure out how will the data be stored and re-used afterwards. GA4 presents some severe limits since you can not transfer nested objects to the tool.

It would be easier to work through Big Query or any DB alternative to store this kind information (but not every company wants to use these kinds of tools :D). Today I feel limited because I am forced to sort the resources by minimum, maximum, average because I will encount limits with GA4 custom dimensions limits + Data Studio limitations too.

Hope this update will help. :)